# Not able to close modal pop up window after form submission

Tags: angularjs

```js
angular.module("simpleModalPop").controller("applicationListCtrl", [ "$scope", "masterService", "$rootScope", "Notification", "applicationService", "Constant", "$filter", "$state","$uibModal",
    function($scope, masterService, $rootScope, Notification, applicationService, Constant,$filter,$state, $uibModal) {
        console.log("applicationListCtrl....--->");
        $scope.modalInstanceObj = {};
        $scope.openModal = function(selected) {
            if($scope.currentObj.coApplicantUserId == 5){
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    ariaLabelledBy : 'modal-title',
                    ariaDescribedBy : 'modal-body',
                    templateUrl : 'application/coApplicantProfile.html',
                    controller : 'profCtrl',
                    controllerAs : '$ctrl',
                    size : 'lg',
                    resolve : {
                    }
                });

                modalInstance.result.then(function(){
                    console.log("Modal is dimissed !");
                },
                function(res){
                    $scope.currentObj.coApplicantUserId={};
                });

                $scope.modalInstanceObj = modalInstance;
            }
        }

    } ]);

angular.module("simpleModalPop").controller("profCtrl", function($scope, userService) {

    $scope.initUserObj();
    $scope.createNewCoApplicant = function(){
        console.log("createNewCoApplicant");

        userService.creatCoApplicantProfile().then(
                function(success) {
                    $scope.isDisable = false;
                    if(success.data.status == 200){
                        $scope.modalInstanceObj.close('closed');
                    }else{
                        console.log(success.data.message);
                    }
                }, function(error) {
                    $scope.isDisable = false;                   
                    $scope.modalInstanceObj.close('closed');
         });        
    }

});
```

Above is my js file, and trying to close modal pop up screen after form submission. but it is giving me an error

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined"

I have already injected `['ui.bootstrap']` in another js file. I am using angularjs **V 1.7.x**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

Inject `$uibModalInstance` into the controller  `profCtrl`

Replace   `$scope.modalInstanceObj.close('closed');` with  `$uibModalInstance.close('closed');`

```
angular.module("simpleModalPop").controller("profCtrl", function($scope,$uibModalInstance,userService) {

    $scope.initUserObj();
    $scope.createNewCoApplicant = function(){
        console.log("createNewCoApplicant");

        userService.creatCoApplicantProfile().then(
                function(success) {
                    $scope.isDisable = false;
                    if(success.data.status == 200){
                      $uibModalInstance.close('closed'); //replaced  $scope.modalInstanceObj.close('closed');
                    }else{
                        console.log(success.data.message);
                    }
                }, function(error) {
                    $scope.isDisable = false;                   
                    $uibModalInstance.close('closed');
         });        
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in  these type of lines

```
$scope.modalInstanceObj.close
```

Since $scope.modalInstanceObj is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined '$scope.modalInstanceObj' in 'applicationListCtrl' controller while you are trying to access the same from another scope which is of 'profCtrl' controller. Try using events if the two templates / controllers are siblings or try to access using parent / child properties.

Comment: Its my fault pasting wrong version of file, I declared $scope.modalInstanceObj = {}; as well. I will modify the code version again.

Comment: Adding $scope.modalInstanceObj = {}; to the 'applicationListCtrl' controller still keeps modalInstanceObj object confined to the controller itself. While trying to access the variable from another controller, the $scope changes. You may try using $rootScope to set and access the modal instance for the same and check if it works.